# Filter Issue in Ext.Net Grid Panel

Tags: ext.net

I am developing an application using Ext.Net, here in the Gridpanel I am facing problem with filters in it.

After I searched for the desired string in the filter the paging in the grid is not working properly and some times the filter option is appearing twice in the grid panel.

Why?

Comment: Hello! Can you provide example of this?

Comment: "<Plugins>
<ext:GridFilters runat="server" ID="gfSamples" Local="true">
<Filters>
<ext:StringFilter DataIndex="SamplePointName" />
<ext:StringFilter DataIndex="SamplePointTagNo" />
<ext:StringFilter DataIndex="Area">
 </ext:StringFilter>
<ext:StringFilter DataIndex="Location">
</ext:StringFilter>
<ext:StringFilter DataIndex="EquipmentName">
</ext:StringFilter>
</Filters>
</ext:GridFilters>
</Plugins>"

Answer (score 0):

you should update your ext.net component. when I develop an application using string filter, there's no problem. and please describe more specify.